# How to avoid showing copies of changed files between commits

Tags: git, file, copy, git-diff

I'm writing a bash script which goes through all the commits in a project and displays files that have been changed.
Here is the script:

```
    for sha in $(git log origin/master --pretty=oneline | grep -e "pattern" | awk '{print $1}')
    do
         git --no-pager diff $sha~1 $sha --name-only
    done
```

But the output of this script shows the same file multiple times. My question is how to avoid showing copies of some of the files and display them only once?
I read the `git diff` documentation and tried `---minimal` and `--histogram` algorithms, but it doesn't work. I also tried `| sort -k2 -u` but it still display copies of files. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `done | sort -u`.

Comment: Hi ElpieKay, thank you for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried ```uniq``` also, but my output is still the same.

Comment: Why do diff comiit by commit? Why not all at once? `git diff --name-only origin/master master`

Comment: @phd because I figured I need to list files changed in every commit.

Comment: @irena That I don;t understand. On one hand, "*I need to list files changed in every commit*", on the other hand "*avoid showing copies of some of the files*". These are contradictory requirement, you'd better explain more clear what you really want. List changes in every commit? What if some files are changed in multiple commits?

Comment: @phd because after my online research for ```git diff``` to show the files that have been changed I must pass two arguments so that it shows what has been changed. In this case those two arguments are commit's SHA numbers ```sha~1``` and ```sha```

Comment: @phd Those two arguments can be ```HEAD``` and ```HEAD~N``` for example.

Comment: @irena In the command I advised above these 2 args are `origin/master` and `master`. I don't see any need for a loop over every commit.

Comment: Restating what @phd said, you either want to see changes at every commit, in which case you *should* see the same file listed multiple times, or you want to see the summary of all changes between two commits in which case you should just do exactly that. Perhaps if you said *why* you want to do this it would be clearer. (What do you intend to do with, or learn from, the results of your script?)

Comment: Some ideas on how to get others to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TTT the script is needed to see the changed files in a project, so that these files could be easier to track later on.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a new script which looks like this:

```
   
   first-script.sh $1 > output.txt
   sort -u output.txt
```

which sorts the files and removes duplicates from output.txt.
The `first-script.sh` is the original one from my question:

```
 for sha in $(git log origin/master --pretty=oneline | grep -e "pattern" | awk '{print $1}')
    do
         git --no-pager diff $sha~1 $sha --name-only
    done
```

which lists the changed files between commits.
In terminal, the script is run by typing the name of the second script (the one that sorts the files and removes duplicates from output.txt) and the name of the project for which you want to see the files that have been changed as an argument like this:
`second-script "name-of-the-project"`